# HOW TO Using ADOQuery sum in Delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi-7, delphi-xe2, tadoquery

I have this SQL query:

[image]

As you can see, it works fine.  Except when I use it in Delphi.

I use TDBLookupComboBox, TEdit, and TButton.  My idea is, whenever I click on the TButton, the EXE goes to check the table in SQL using information in the DBLookupComboBox and puts the result in the TEdit.

This is my Delphi code:

[image]

Comment: And, your question is...? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Delphi code, you are using double quotes:  `"`

Your string needs to be enclosed in single quotes:  `'`

To embed a single quote in your Delphi string, need to use two single quotes: `''`

```
S := 'hey"there';        // hey"there

S := 'hey''there';       // hey'there

S := 'specification='''; // specification='

S := '''';               // '
```

Comment: like this :  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('where specification =;"'+dblookupcombobox1.text+'"'); ???

Comment: Using a parametrized query would not only make this work better, even if the user would enter a single quote in the DBLookupCombo, but it would also protect against sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Chr(39) in delphi = " ' " sign.
```

I hope it will be helpful.

```
Begin
AdoQuery1.SQL.Clear;
AdoQuery1.SQL.Add('Select Sum(Cast(Total As Float)) As tot From machine Where Specification='+Chr(39)+dbLookupComboBox1.Text+Chr(39));
AdoQuery1.Open;
End;
```